# how save is apk file

Tags: android, apk

i want to give my app to a few people forr testing before i commit it to the store.
Now i want to prevent them from being able to spread the app for free.
My idea is to add the following code to the OnCreate-method of my mainActivity:

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
boolean success = false;
for(int i= 0; i < 4; i++) {
    success = client.requestTime(String.format("%d.de.pool.ntp.org",i),10000);
    if(success) break;
}
if(success) {
    long now = client.getNtpTime();
    Date date = new Date(now);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date limit = simpleDateFormat.parse("15.10.2015",new ParsePosition(0));
    if(limit.before(date)) finish();
} else {
    finish();
}
```

This would make the .apk file useless after the sprecified date, wouldn't it?
or is there a way to get the code out of the file?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. I **assume** you implement in-app payments or Google in-app licensing. If so, you should just add your testers addresses in your console, so the license validation for them would pass. If they decide to spread the app, next user shall fail on license validation.

Comment: Yes, Play Store has an official beta-testing mechanism, use that.

Answer (score 1):

Play Store provides a safe beta-testing mechanism, use this instead of distributing a raw .apk file.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Answer (score -1):

If the `client.requestTime` is not important for you do this in your main Activity's onCreate, remove the rest:

```
Date date = new Date(now);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date limit = formatter.parse("15.10.2015");
if(limit.before(date)){
    finish();
}
```

If the current date is after `"15.10.2015"` the app will close.

Comment: This will still allow the app to be used if the user changes device time.